# tangent vector of a disk embedded in R^3

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary, tangent-spaces

Consider in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the plane $N: x+y+z=0$ and the sphere $S: (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)=r$, where $r$ is fixed.

The intersection $N\cap S$ is the disk embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
I would like to know the (a) tangent vector of $D$ at its boundary.

Write $n_D(x)$ the tangent at $x$ of $D$,  $n_S(x)$ the tangent at $x$ of $S$,  $n_N(x)$ the tangent at $x$ of $N$.

Do we have that $n_D(x)$ is linearly dependant of  $n_N\wedge n_S$ ?

I feel like the notion of tangent vector in this case is not well defined.

Comment: the intersection of a plane and a sphere is not a disk but a lower dimensional sphere or a point, plus you forgot a square on your definition of S, but indeed the notion of tangent vector at the edge of a variety is not defined (at least for the disk) you need to have a nieghbourhood around your point which works for the sphere (it has no boundary).